# JavaFx synchronize two Services

Tags: rest, service, javafx, synchronization

I'm looking for an idea how to synchronize two javafx.concurrent.Service. 
Each service is calling a REST endpoint to load data. I like to synchronize both services.
Only when both services are read I like to update my screen elements.
Both services are working with EventHandler callbacks. Is there a standard pattern in JavaFx for doing that?

Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Manuel

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be to listen to the `Worker.State` of the services:

```
  firstService.stateProperty().isEqualTo(State.SUCCEEDED)
              .and(secondService.stateProperty().isEqualTo(State.SUCCEEDED))
                    .addListener((ov, b, b1) -> {
                        if(b1){
                          // udpateUI
                        } 
                    });
```

If Java 8 is an option, you can have a look at its `CompletableFuture`, and use e.g.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> service1);
CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> service2);

CompletableFuture<Void> finished = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2);
        finished.thenRun(() -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                // updateUI
            });
        });
```